# set Items list to multiple pivot tables

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table, olap

Been trying to set same items list to multiple OLAP pivot tables based on the changes I do in one out of the many pivot tables in a workbook.

The recorded macro is (this removes old selections as well):

```
Sub GetPivotFilter()

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabell4").PivotFields( _
    "[DimCampaign].[Campaigns].[Campaign]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
    "[DimCampaign].[Campaigns].[Campaign].&[106679]", _ 'generated after i select campaing
    "[DimCampaign].[Campaigns].[Campaign].&[106680]", _'generated after i select campaing

    "[DimCampaign].[Campaigns].[Campaign].&[107049]")'generated after i select campaing


End Sub
```

*1* How can i extract the changes I do in the first pivot (i wont know the numbers before i make the change)?

*2* How can I get this to apply to those pivot tables that has the option to add campaign?

The solution I have at the moment looks messy, but works:

```
Sub SetPivotFilter()

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabell4").PivotFields( _
"[DimCampaign].[Campaigns].[Campaign]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
"[DimCampaign].[Campaigns].[Campaign].&[106679]", _     
"[DimCampaign].[Campaigns].[Campaign].&[106680]", _    
"[DimCampaign].[Campaigns].[Campaign].&[107049]")
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabell18").PivotFields( _
"[DimCampaign].[Campaigns].[Campaign]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
"[DimCampaign].[Campaigns].[Campaign].&[106679]", _     
"[DimCampaign].[Campaigns].[Campaign].&[106680]", _    
"[DimCampaign].[Campaigns].[Campaign].&[107049]")
'and so on
End Sub
```

All help is much appreciated

Comment: Question - are 106679 , 106680, 107049 all items in Pivot Field `Campaign` ?

Comment: @ShaiRado yes, this time, but NeXT time i need to change campaign there could be more or less selected items

Comment: see my answer below, it doesn't include setting the Pivot table and fields, only filtering the items you requested in all Pivot Tables

Answer (score 0):

The code below loops through all PivotTable Names is `pvtTblNameArr` (array), in Sheet name "***SheetPivot***" (modify according to your sheet name).

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetPivotFilter()

Dim PvtTbl              As PivotTable
Dim pvtitem             As PivotItem
Dim pvtFld              As PivotField
Dim pvtTblNameArr()     As Variant
Dim i                   As Integer

' modify this array to all PivotTable names you need to modify (in the same sheet)
pvtTblNameArr() = Array("Pivottabell4", "Pivottabell8")

' loop though Pivot Table Names
For i = LBound(pvtTblNameArr) To UBound(pvtTblNameArr)

    ' change "SheetPivot" to your sheet name
    Set PvtTbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetPivot").PivotTables(pvtTblNameArr(i))

    ' set Pivot field variable to "Campaign"
    Set pvtFld = PvtTbl.PivotFields("Campaign")

    ' lop through all Pivot Items in "Campaign" Pivot Field
    For Each pvtitem In pvtFld.PivotItems

        Select Case pvtitem.Name
            Case 106679, 106680, 107049
                pvtitem.Visible = True

            Case Else
                pvtitem.Visible = False

        End Select

    Next pvtitem

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: That solves part of **2** and this helps. Get a `run-time error 1004` here:     `Set pvtFld = PvtTbl.PivotFields("Campaign")`. Cant get PivotFields-attribute to PivotTable-class

Comment: @krib can you be more specific ? when did you get this error ? after it ran ok on 1 Pivot ? not all ? Do all of your Pivot Tables sit in the same sheet ?

Comment: I tried to step through it (trying to learn) and got that error on that line before anything was altered.
Not all are in that one sheet, but that I can figure out.

Comment: I tired to simulate an error, only thing I could think of is if your PivotTable name is different than in the array, ot if "Campaign" is somehow spelled differently ?

Comment: tried a few times, ends up with the same error on the same line `Set pvtFld = PvtTbl.PivotFields("Campaign")`

Comment: you are not helping me solve this, can you answer my questions above ?

Comment: copied pivottable names directly from the pivot and `Campaign` is also correct. Everything from my original post is from recorded macro. Your help is much appreciated, make no mistake about that ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121166/discussion-between-shai-rado-and-krib).